# How to install llvm on windows?

Tags: windows, llvm

What is the best way to install `llvm` on windows?

All the information I found refers to build it manually. Is there a better option to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you On a machine using Windows 11 and having the command line installer scoop installed, I have managed to install llvm easily just running:

```
scoop install main/llvm
```

Answer (score 0):

You might as well just [download the installer](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-18.1.1/LLVM-18.1.1-win64.exe), or, disputably equally good as `scoop`, install it with [Chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/llvm):

```
choco install llvm
```